# How do I run a beam file compiled by Elixir or Erlang?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have installed Erlang/OTP and Elixir, and compiled the HelloWorld program into a BEAM using the command:

```
elixirc test.ex
```

Which produced a file named Elixir.Hello.beam

How do I run this file?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Short answer: no way to know for sure without also knowing the contents of your source file :)

There are a few ways to run Elixir code. This answer will be an overview of various workflows that can be used with Elixir.

When you are just getting started and want to try things out, launching `iex` and evaluating expressions one at a time is the way to go.

```
iex(5)> Enum.reverse [1,2,3,4]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

You can also get help on Elixir modules and functions in `iex`. Most of the functions have examples in their docs.

```
iex(6)> h Enum.reverse

                        def reverse(collection)

Reverses the collection.
[...]
```

---

When you want to put some code into a file to reuse it later, the recommended (and de facto standard) way is to create a mix project and start adding modules to it. But perhaps, you would like to know what's going on under the covers before relying on mix to perform common tasks like compiling code, starting applications, and so on. Let me explain that.

The simplest way to put some expressions into a file and run it would be to use the `elixir` command.

```
x = :math.sqrt(1234)
IO.puts "Your square root is #{x}"
```

Put the above fragment of code into a file named `simple.exs` and run it with `elixir simple.exs`. The `.exs` extension is just a convention to indicate that the file is meant to be evaluated (and that is what we did).

This works up until the point you want to start building a project. Then you will need to organize your code into modules. Each module is a collection of functions. It is also the minimal compilation unit: each module is compiled into a `.beam` file. Usually people have one module per source file, but it is also fine to define more than one. Regardless of the number of modules in a single source file, each module will end up in its own `.beam` file when compiled.

```
defmodule M do
  def hi(name) do
    IO.puts "Hello, #{name}"
  end
end
```

We have defined a module with a single function. Save it to a file named `mymod.ex`. We can use it in multiple ways:

- launch `iex` and evaluate the code in the spawned shell session:

  ```
  $ iex mymod.ex

  iex> M.hi "Alex"
  Hello, Alex
  :ok
  ```
- evaluate it before running some other code. For example, to evaluate a single expression on the command line, use `elixir -e <expr>`. You can "require" (basically, evaluate and load) one or more files before it:

  ```
  $ elixir -r mymod.ex -e 'M.hi "Alex"'
  Hello, Alex
  ```
- compile it and let the code loading facility of the VM find it

  ```
  $ elixirc mymod.ex
  $ iex
  iex> M.hi "Alex"
  Hello, Alex
  :ok
  ```

In that last example we compiled the module which produced a file named `Elixir.M.beam` in the current directory. When you then run `iex` in the same directory, the module will be loaded the first time a function from it is called. You could also use other ways to evaluate code, like `elixir -e 'M.hi "..."'`. As long as the `.beam` file can be found by the code loader, the module will be loaded and the appropriate function in it will be executed.

---

However, this was all about trying to play with some code examples. When you are ready to build a project in Elixir, you will need to use `mix`. The workflow with `mix` is more or less as follows:

```
$ mix new myproj
* creating README.md
* creating .gitignore
* creating mix.exs
[...]

$ cd myproj

# 'mix new' has generated a dummy test for you
# see test/myproj_test.exs
$ mix test
```

Add new modules in the `lib/` directory. It is customary to prefix all module names with your project name. So if you take the `M` module we defined above and put it into the file `lib/m.ex`, it'll look like this:

```
 defmodule Myproj.M do
   def hi(name) do
     IO.puts "Hello, #{name}"
   end
 end
```

Now you can start a shell with the Mix project loaded in it.

```
 $ iex -S mix
```

Running the above will compile all your source file and will put them under the `_build` directory. Mix will also set up the code path for you so that the code loader can locate `.beam` files in that directory.

Evaluating expressions in the context of a mix project looks like this:

```
$ mix run -e 'Myproj.M.hi "..."'
```

Again, no need to compile anything. Most mix tasks will recompile any changed files, so you can safely assume that any modules you have defined are available when you call functions from them.

Run `mix help` to see all available tasks and `mix help <task>` to get a detailed description of a particular task.

Comment: This is awesome @android, and as I mentioned elsewhere, hopefully gets into the Elixir getting started section soon :)

Comment: @SamuelLampa it'd be nice if you could open an issue on the elixir-lang.github.com project, indicating where you would expect to find this explanation in the guide

Comment: I was hoping some of the elxiir devs might just go on and add it immediately, but indeed, opening an issue is a good idea!

Answer (score 16):

To specifically address the question:

```
$ elixirc test.ex
```

will produce a file named `Elixir.Hello.beam`, if the file defines a `Hello` module.

If you run `elixir` or `iex` from the directory containing this file, the module will be available. So:

```
$ elixir -e Hello.some_function
```

or

```
$ iex

iex(1)> Hello.some_function
```

Answer (score 6):

Assume that I write an Elixir program like this:

```
defmodule PascalTriangle do
  defp next_row(m), do: for(x <- (-1..Map.size(m)-1), do: { (x+1), Map.get(m, x, 0) + Map.get(m, x+1, 0) } ) |> Map.new
  def draw(1), do: (IO.puts(1); %{ 0 => 1})
  def draw(n) do
    (new_map = draw(n - 1) |> next_row ) |> Map.values |> Enum.join(" ") |> IO.puts
    new_map
  end
end
```

The module PascalTriangle can be used like this: `PascalTriangle.draw(8)`

When you use `elixirc` to compile the ex file, it will create a file called **Elixir.PascalTriangle.beam**.

From command line, you can execute the beam file like this:

`elixir -e "PascalTriangle.draw(8)"`

You can see the output similar to the photo:
[image]