# How to compile single file in elixir?

Tags: elixir

How to compile to executable in terminal file an elixir file?

I read that to compile elixir I need to create new project.
But file, that I want to compile is
`IO.puts "hello world"`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a **[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have **[tried so far](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**, and take the **[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)**

Comment: If you want an executable (in the sense of not needing the Erlang runtime) then you're out of luck. Neither Erlang nor Elixir can create a stand alone executable.

Answer (score 3):

To compile from shell, first create a file:

```
# module_name.ex
defmodule ModuleName do
  def hello do
    IO.puts "Hello World"
  end
end
```

Then run shell and compile:

```
Interactive Elixir
iex> c("module_name.ex")
[ModuleName]
iex> ModuleName.hello
Hello world!
:ok
```

Code is copied from [A Crash Course - Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#elixir)

If you want to use `elixirc`, read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31485826/1173020

Comment: It's cool but i need for byte code that could run from terminal.

Comment: I gave a link to another answer, it's about running code from terminal.

Answer (score 3):

**You can compile an elixir file using the `elixirc` command.**

So if you have a file named `file.ex`, you can run:

```
elixirc file.ex
```

This will create a `.beam` file in the current directory for each module defined in your file. If you start `iex` in this directory your modules from the file will be available.

[Here](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules-and-functions.html#compilation) you can read more about this command in the official guides.

Answer (score 1):

You can also execute from command line. Save the file with a .exs extension (file.exs).

For example file.exs contains this line of code:

```
IO.puts "Hello World"
```

Then execute it with elixir from command line like this:

```
$ elixir file.exs
Hello World
```

[Elixir website has helpful instructions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/introduction.html#running-scripts)

Hope this helped!

Comment: An .exs is not compiled though, right? The question was how to compile a file.